# Alexa - Error with built-ins intents on service simulator after adding Google Analytics

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I am building a custom skill. Before adding google analytics, the 3 built-ins & 2 customs intents were all working properly, both when tested from AWS console and the service simulator. Now, I get 'The response is invalid' from the service simulator, ONLY for the built-ins intents (the 2 customs intents give a correct lambda response). Here is what have changed in my code since the last working version:

Adding:

```
var express = require('express'), request = require('request'), app = express(), GA_TRACKING_ID = 'UA_TRACKING_ID';

function trackEvent(category, action, label, value, cb) {
  console.log('1');
  var data = {v: '1', tid: GA_TRACKING_ID, cid: '555', t: 'event', ec: category, ea: action, el: label, ev: value,};
  request.post(
    'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect', {
      form: data
    },
    function(err, response) {
      console.log('2');
      if (err) { console.log('3'); return cb(err); }
      if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log('4');
        return cb(new Error('Tracking failed'));
      }
      console.log('5');
      cb();
    }
  );
}
```

And calling the trackEvent function, similarly in all intents:

**Built-in intent example**: (=> testing this intent logs out '1' in the CloudWatch, and then execution stops)

```
'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function (intent, session, response) {
   var self = this;
   trackEvent('Intent', 'AMAZON.CancelIntent', 'stop', '100', function(err) {
     if (err) { return next(err); }
     self.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
     self.emit(':responseReady');
   });
},
```

**Example in a custom intent**: (=> testing this intent will output the correct speechOutput)

```
'DressingTodayIntent': function(intent, session, response) {
  var speechOutput;
  var self = this;
  var cb = getJSON('...', function(err, forecast) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error occurred while trying to retrieve data', err);
    } else {
      speechOutput = getDressingAdvice(forecast, true);
    }
      self.response.cardRenderer("Your advice for today:", speechOutput);
      self.response.speak(speechOutput);
      self.emit(':responseReady');
  });
  trackEvent('Intent', 'DressingTodayIntent', 'DressingToday', '100', cb);
}
```

I insist, 'AMAZON.CancelIntent', 'AMAZON.HelpIntent', 'AMAZON.StopIntent' (& 'LaunchRequest') are not working, **only** since I added GA. What did I do wrong?

Last reference, the working intent code, before adding GA:

```
'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
  this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
  this.emit(':responseReady');
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the built-in intent example that did not work, all I needed to do was replacing the actual function inside trackEvent by a callback, like this:

```
'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function (intent, session, response) {
  var self = this;

  var callback = function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    console.log(STOP_MESSAGE);
    self.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
    self.emit(':responseReady');
  };
  trackEvent('Intent', 'AMAZON.CancelIntent', 'Cancel', '100', callback());
},
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, since i am not too experienced with JS. But have you tried using an arrow function? Something like this maybe..

```
'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function (intent, session, response) {
   // var self = this;
   trackEvent('Intent', 'AMAZON.CancelIntent', 'stop', '100', (err) => {
     if (err) { return next(err); }
     this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
     this.emit(':responseReady');
   });
},
```

Maybe you leave a scope u dont want to leave...

Comment: This solution doesn't work, I still get the exact same result (Invalid lambda response...)